# How to update line after plotting two markers by typing in distance

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js and I want to key in a specific distance, which will then update the already drawn line.

Currently, I am able to plot two markers on a map and draw a line between this two markers using leaflet.js

After this line is drawn, I want to be able to adjust/change the line by keying in the distance. So after keying a specific distance (in meters), the length of line should update accordingly on the map.

How do I change the length of line by typing in required distance?